# When accessing a prop in this.props, return value is null?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, redux

I've created my actions/reducers/store etc. When I pass mapStateToPros to my Shop component, I have access to my props. Specifically on this component I want to use this.props.auth to find the current user that's logged on. On the user there is an isAdmin prop which by default is false. When i call this.props.auth.isAdmin it returns null.

Using node/express/mongoDB for my backend

[localhost error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qq2L.jpg)

[Shop Component top img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aovql.png)

[Shop Component bottom img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxVh1.png)

[Actions for Reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMHJ.png)

[Reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRvKP.png)

Comment: could you show your reducer code?

Comment: edited the post. Added the actions and reducer pics

Comment: Is it because your initial state equals null? Anyway, problems like this can be easily tackled by debugging. In the browser in dev-tools you could simply set breakpoints in all critical places (reducer, mapstatetoprops, etc) and see where the problem lies

Comment: Technically yes. But because I'm using type fetch_user the state should be updated according to the action that i've used. When I call this.props.auth. I receive an object of all the props passed from auth. But once I call this.props.auth.isAdmin, I receive null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the screenshot of your reducer here https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRvKP.png, I would try something like this:

```
// authReducer.js 
const initialState = {
  auth: {
    isAdmin: false,
  },  
  isLoggedOn: false
}

// create a default schema for you state rather than defaulting to null 
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  // the rest of your code
}
```

This will setup your initial redux state on the auth reducer in a way that conforms to what is expected by the component.

For each action, `FETCH_USER` and `LOGOUT_USER`, you will want to return an object with some properties describing the new state, but you currently have it setup where `LOGOUT_USER` returns `false`, which is an entirely different data format (boolean) then what I think you are going for with the representation of auth state (typically youd want an object).

With state changes, a common and handy pattern is to return a new object that merges the old state with the new, so you could end up with something like this for an action:

```
case LOGOUT_USER: 
  return { ...state, action.payload }
```

This ensures your redux state always conforms to a specific shape and helps you avoid null / undefined errors for props in the component.

From there you could dispatch an action to update the isAdmin property to true under a different set of circumstances.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation. That worked perfectly. One small tweak was switching ...state, action.payload to ...state, ...action.payload. Definitely helped prevent mutation. Can't believe I didn't think of it sooner.